# Index expression out of bounds. Attempted to access element 2. The valid range is 1-1

Tags: matlab, indexing, simulink

I am getting an error on each element of the MATLAB function input u.

> Index expression out of bounds. Attempted to access element 2. The valid range is 1-1

I don't know what is causing this problem because it seems as if the input u doesn't recognize as a vector.

```
function y = fcn(u)

%DATOS INICIALES DEL SISTEMA

%entradas u(1) ... u(6) 
Fi=u(1);
Fe=u(2);
Tin=u(3);
cS_in=u(4);
Tin_ag=u(5);
%estados
V=u(6);
Cx=u(7);
Cp=u(8);
Cs=u(9);
Co2=u(10);
Tr=u(11);
Tag=u(12);


y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

[image: simulink model]

Comment: This looks like it should be OK... are you sure that your Simulink function block is pointing to this version of the function? Can you put a breakpoint at the start of the function to see what the input `u` looks like when entering the function?

Comment: It seems like I am actually getting vector values in the input u, and also the scope shows the lines. But the errors still appear: u =
   1.0e+03 *

    0.0510
    0.0100
    0.0250
    0.0400
    0.0150
    1.0040
    0.0089
    0.0245
    0.0458
    0.0286
    0.0490
    0.0430
    0.0420
    0.0870

Comment: Is the quoted error the actual verbatim full error you're getting? I would normal expect wording like "index exceeds matrix dimensions" for errors like this.

Comment: For each element of the u vector after the second one im getting an error like this one: Index expression out of bounds. Attempted to access element 2. The valid range is 1-1.
More information

Function 'MATLAB Function' (#24.93.94), line 8, column 7:
"2"
Launch diagnostic report.

Comment: I just made a trivial [example model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlRyE.png) and had no issues accessing `u(2)` within the function, without showing the behaviour you're seeing when debugging I'm afraid this is almost impossible to reproduce/diagnose. Can you please [edit] your question to show what you're seeing with the breakpoint inside of `fcn` and a command which generates the error there? Can you simplify your model until you don't see the error? The error in your comment seems odd too because it highlights "line 8", but you're using `u(2)` on line 7 above

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could solve the problem, using the Edit Data inside the Matlab Function and giving the size of the vector. Also, for the output I had to put it  transposed (y = [1 2 ...]')
[Property Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpusF.png)
[Edit Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTe0P.png)